# No more plugins ? What platform should plugins like VLC go to now?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, plugins

I've read that soon both Firefox and Chrome plan to stop supporting plugins.

They can be allowed, but mostly when the end user understands a fair amount about how to configure exceptions, etc.

**What is the future platform that plugins, like VLC, for example, should target to work cross browser?**

It supports tons of video formats and media way better than most browsers will for the foreseeable future, and I'm sure there are other plugins out there where it doesn't make sense to port it to html5, or asm.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the best answer I've found is to use Google's "Pepper"

https://github.com/google/pepper.js

> pepper.js is a JavaScript library that enables the compilation of
>   native Pepper applications into JavaScript using Emscripten. This
>   allows the simultaneous deployment of native code on the web both as a
>   Portable Native Client (PNaCl) executable and as JavaScript. Native
>   Pepper applications can now be run in Chrome, Firefox, Internet
>   Explorer, Safari, and more.